# How are we related?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**How are we related?**

[image: a Board]

[image: a Stone]

[image: sticky Note]

[image: playing Card]

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The four objects we see depicted here are:

> A (wooden) **BOARD**, a **STONE**, a (Post-It) **NOTE**, and a (playing) **CARD**.

These are related to each other in that...

> ...they can all be prefixed by the word **KEY** to make other words: KEYBOARD, [KEYSTONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_(architecture)), [KEYNOTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynote) (speech), and KEYCARD.

So I guess that makes 'you'...

> ...the **key** to this whole puzzle!