# What character am I?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**What character am I? What am I from?**

---

[image: Here's where I'm going]

---

The clues:

- Graduation hat
- a movie Script
- a puppetMaster
- an Office
- a Turtle
- a Car
- a Dent
- a Flame
- a Field
- a Mobile phone
- a Man
- a Ball
- a Line
- a Phone
- a Board

---

Linked: [How are we related?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120800/how-are-we-related)

Comment: Do the image sequences wrap around the line breaks?  (i.e. is it 3 sequences or 5?)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore No, the lines create 5 sets of 3 images.

Comment: After seeing the solution I suggest the "knowledge" tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are:

> OP edit: **[The Postman](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Postman)** (previously thought to be **[Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(The_Legend_of_Zelda))**) in the N64 game, *[The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Majora%27s_Mask)*.

Because:

> Each image can be represented by a word - helpfully, these words are capitalised in the text description beneath them! - and for each triplet of images it is possible to find a word that will precede all three of these words to form other real words:
>
>  **POST**: POST-graduation, POSTscript, POSTmaster.
>  **BOX**: BOX office, [BOX turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_turtle), BOXcar.
>  **IN**: INdent, INflame, INfield.
>  **SNOW**: SNOWmobile, SNOWman, SNOWball.
>  **HEAD**: HEADline, HEADphone, HEADboard.

Reading these off as a sentence gives us a phrase - you're heading to the...

> ...**postbox in Snowhead**. Where is [Snowhead](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Snowhead_Region)? It's a location in the aforementioned *Majora's Mask*. Why a [postbox](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Postbox)? To drop off some mail, of course!

> <s>And since in that game the player controls the protagonist, Link, I think it's highly likely that you must be **Link**!</s>
>  And since in that game the postman is constantly running around delivering letters, it must be him!

Comment: Very close! You got the "what am I from" part right, but the actual character is a bit more subtle....

Comment: @Tyler Hmm... I don't know the game well enough to know who this might be then. When I google this it brings up references to rot13(yrggref orvat cbfgrq va n fgbelyvar vaibyivat [Nawh naq Xnsrv](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Reuniting_Kafei_and_Anju) but I can't find anything definitive linking one or the other to this specific location... I imagine what you're looking for revolves around a storyline moment like that.

Comment: @TylerSelden Edits should ["clarify the meaning of the post (without *changing* that meaning)"](/help/privileges/edit) -- while an OP may occasionally make some clarifying edits to an answer to add information the answerer  is unlikely to, such edits shouldn't actually (e.g.) change what the given answer is. It's always best to give an answerer hints to get them across the finish line, rather than fix their answer for them. (Taken uncharitably, changing someone's answer for them sends the message that you think them incapable of ever figuring this out themselves; surely you don't mean that.)